# Automapper throwing exception when trying to map specific dictionary item by key and key doesnt exist

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm using ASP.NET Core and I'm using Automapper to map between my model and viewmodel. In my model I have a dictionary of objects. In my mapping function I'm mapping only one of the objects from the dictionary to an object in the wiewmodel based on a specific key. I have no issues if the key exists for at least one of the models in the list but if the key doesnt exist for any of the model objects in the list the mapping fails.

Here is my model:

```
namespace SylectusTL.Models.User
{
    public class User
    {
        public uint user_id { get; set; }       
        public string user_name { get; set; }
        public uint active { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<uint, Address.PhoneNumber> phone_numbers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my viewmodel:

```
namespace SylectusTL.ViewModels.Account
{
    public class UserViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "User ID")]
        public uint user_id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "User Name")]
        public string user_name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        public bool active { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public PhoneNumber office_phone { get; set; }
        public PhoneNumber fax { get; set; }
        public PhoneNumber home_phone { get; set; }
        public PhoneNumber cell_phone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the mapping config I have:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Models.User.User, ViewModels.Account.UserViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.active, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => Convert.ToBoolean(src.active)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.office_phone, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => (src.phone_numbers.Where(p => p.Key == 1).First().Value)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.fax, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => (src.phone_numbers.Where(p => p.Key == 3).First().Value)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.home_phone, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => (src.phone_numbers.Where(p => p.Key == 2).First().Value)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.cell_phone, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => (src.phone_numbers.Where(p => p.Key == 4).First().Value)));
    }
}
```

So what is happening is for my specific query there are no users with a fax type number so there is no key 3 in the dictionary. This is causing an exception when I'm trying to map. This exception doesnt happen if at least one user in the list has a dictionary with the key being looked for. Eg. only one user has a cell (key 4) so the mapping doesnt fail.

Is there a way to ignore this property if there is no key 3? I tried NullSubstitute but that doesnt seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Replace `First` with `FirstOrDefault` as a quick fix, but using LINQ to get item by key from dictionary is really strange (because that's one of the primary operations supported by dictionary).

Comment: Yea I realize now that Im just over complicating things by using linq, I'm going to try FirstOrDefault and I'm going to get rid of the linq too. Thanks!

Comment: just to add to my previous comment, I tried replacing the mapfrom I show above with MapFrom(src => src.phone_numbers[3]) and it still fails because no users have a fax